# SLURM dependency on nonexistent job ID

Tags: slurm, hpc

Submitting a job with `sbatch --dependency=afterok:$dependencylist` should make the current submission wait until jobs with IDs in `$dependencylist` have concluded with an exit code `0`. What happens if some or all IDs in `$dependencylist` are not valid job IDs or have never been submitted? Will SLURM recognize it and start the jobs?

Alternatively, how can I provide empty arguments to `sbatch`? I tried `sbatch --dependency=afterok:""`, but SLURM complains that `sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem`. The reason I want to keep the `--dependency` option is that I'm writing a more general script where at times I will have some dependencies and other times I won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if some or all IDs in $dependencylist are not valid job IDs or have never been submitted?

From a test made with Slurm 20.02.7, it appears that is the job ID is unknown from `slurmctld` (either not submitted yet, or job from earlier in the past than what is configured as `MinJobAge`), the option is silently ignored. `scontrol show job` says then  `Dependency=(null)`. This does not change afterwards, even if a job with that ID appears.

> Alternatively, how can I provide empty arguments to sbatch?

You can take advantage of the above-described behaviour by using "0" as job ID when no dependency is required. Depending on the version, you can also try `-d afterok:-1`, or, try setting a dependency on a past job that successfully completed.

Comment: Not sure if this is due to a different version or a setting changed on our HPC, `-1` worked for me.

Comment: Seconded, for slurm 22.05.3 using `-d afterok:-1` works, but `-d afterok:0` does not work.